# Wordpress TinyMCE button to add a piece of code at the bottom of the post?

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

I'm currently looking to see if there's a Wordpress plugin like a tinyMCE button that will allow me to add custom code at the end of the post, something like:

```
<h3>please enter title</h3
<div id="content">please enter content</div>
```

If you don't know of any plugin could you direct me to some tutorials on how to create a custom button?

Thanks a lot!

Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a WP specific tut http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link to a tutorial](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) on how to write a custom plugin. You will need to use it to insert a custom button with a custom functionality. It is not that difficult.